# How to Answer or reject incoming calls programmatically in Android 9+?

Tags: android, call, phone-call, telephonymanager

I am making an app that programmatically accepts an incoming call without being the default calling application. It has been easier to achieve in Android 9 and below with `tm.acceptRingingCall()` and `tm.endCall`. Unfortunately these methods have been deprecated starting Android 10. According to documentation it can be done using the `InCallService` API. But is it possible to do that without being the default calling app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. From Android 10 onwards the only way to handle phone calls is by using the `InCallService` APIs. I have made a basic dialer app in java that explains basics of how to handle calls as a default dialer app (link: https://github.com/adnan-creator/java-custom-dialer). So for now the best solution is to be the default dialer app till you need the functionality of programmatically accepting or rejecting calls. Then you can transfer the controls back to the inbuilt dialer app.

This can be done by initially storing the package name of the inbuilt dialer before taking control using
`telecomManager.getDefaultDialerPackage()`.

The control can then be passed back to the inbuilt dialer app

```
Intent intent = (new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER))
                    .putExtra(
                     TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, 
                     storedPackageName);
this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER);
```

Comment: Is it possible to selectively auto answer or auto reject an incoming call based on the Calling Party Number in a SIP call?